# How to convert Array like object (String::match result) to Array in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, string, match

I have this code:

```js
const tokens = [
  {
    re: /^(#.*)$/,
    parse: function(line: string) {
      const style = styles.header;
      return {
        content: line,
        style,
      };
    }
  },
  {
    re: /^(__)([^_]+)(__)/,
    parse: function(_:string, g1:string, text:string, g2:string) {
       return {
         content: text
       };
    }
  }
];

const createChunks = (text: string) => {
  return text.split('\n').map((line: string) => {
    const chunk_parser = tokens.find(({re}) => re.test(line));
    if (chunk_parser) {
      const { parse, re } = chunk_parser;
      const m = line.match(re);
      if (m) {
        return parse(...m);
      }
    }
    return {
      content: line
    };
  });
}
```

The problem is that I can't convert the result of String::match to ARray even if that is an Array-like object. NodeJS even shows it as an array in the console. I can use the spread operator or Array.from to covert match result to Array in JavaScript, but TypeScript doesn't allow this and throws this error:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

when using spread, and:

> argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to the parameter of type 'string'

When using Array.from.

This is output from NodeJS:

```
> '# foo'.match(/^(#.*)$/)
[ '# foo', '# foo', index: 0, input: '# foo', groups: undefined ]
> [...'# foo'.match(/^(#.*)$/)]
[ '# foo', '# foo' ]
```

Comment: The more I look at this the less I understand what you're doing with this code. Does `parse()` ever take a full `RegExpMatchArray` rest parameter? Maybe you could provide a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates why you're not just passing in `parse(line)` or `parse(m[0])`?  If you can show that, maybe I'd do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4Qkew), but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @jcalz I want to have multiple functions as parse one may use one full match and the other can use every group the same as the replace callback function has. As you can see this is array so it can have multiple parse functions. I want to have a generic code that will work the same as replace, not only with one argument.

Comment: @jcalz I've updated the question. I think that this does what I want `token.parse(matches[0], ...matches.slice(1))` can you explain how it works and why I can't use `token.parse(...matches.slice(0))`. For me, it looks like a bug in TypeScript.

Comment: The problem is that `RegExpMatchArray` is defined as a subtype of `Array<string>` with a known present `0` property.  Conceptually it should be a subtype of the open-ended tuple type `[string, ...string[]]` but you can't extend tuple types.  So unfortunately when you spread it, the compiler treats it like `string[]` and forgets that it will definitely have a first element.  You could also do `parse(...(matches as [string, ...string[]])` and that should work too. Which approach would you like me to include in my answer?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, you can add this as an answer. I think that people most of the time read the answer and don't want to read the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of [`RegExp`'s `match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) in TypeScript is `RegExpMatchArray | null`.  The [definition of `RegExpMatchArray`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8dfbfcb05809940333b60ba209ace7e7b896dcf7/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L944-L957) looks like

```
interface RegExpMatchArray extends Array<string> {
  0: string;
  index?: number;
  input?: string;
}
```

so it is a subtype of `string[]` with a few extra properties.  Importantly, a `RegExpMatchArray` is known to have a defined `string` element at the index `0`; that is, the first element of the array cannot be undefined.

But unfortunately, when you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) a `RegExpMatchArray` in TypeScript, it treats it like `string[]` and loses track of the added information that `0` is present.  This is the main source of your problem.

I'd say this is a design limitation of TypeScript, although in my searching through GitHub issues I don't really see anyone complaining about spreading a `RegExpMatchArray`, so I don't have an authoritative source for that classification.  But in any case you'll need to work around it.

---

If you want to spread a `RegExpMatchArray` in TypeScript and have it work, you would need to switch to using the [open-ended tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) `[string, ...string[]]`.  But TypeScript doesn't see `RegExpMatchArray` as assignable to that type (essentially the same reason it's not spreadable), so you'd need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

Therefore the approach I'd probably use is this:

```
interface Token {
  re: RegExp;
  parse(
    line: string,
    ...matches: string[]
  ): { content: string, style?: string }
}

const tokens: Token[] = { ⋯ }
```

Here I'm letting the compiler know that the `parse()` methods can be called with any positive number of `string` arguments.  If you don't do this then the compiler will see your individual `parse()` implementations and complain if you pass an arbitrary-length array to something that only accepts, say, two or three inputs.

And then we can use the requisite type assertion:

```
return parse(...(m as [string, ...string[]]));
```

If you don't want to use a type assertion and loosen type safety, you could manually index into the `RegExpMatchArray` with the `0` key and then slice the rest:

```
return parse(m[0], ...m.slice(1));
```

That has a runtime effect but is more "safe" since the compiler can tell that `m` actually does have a `0` index.

Either way you should be able to proceed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsDWETIN4CwAUMslBAFzIBKEA5gKIAeADgNzGktxQDOEACk6lkAG1CVkvMFFB0ANMNIA6VQFs4YBAAsIvKtNkg6AbQC6wgJRU8yBOnA4wBmXPlSwAT1EQA-C6M6ZABfYlCiYnsQaWQwLBx9NHiQc2QAXmQTYUISEXIqAHoAPQEAYmUAKksAEgLFXK4efioYAFcQBDBgB2QBcRBJQzlLfCURKJjpbxQMgCIpn15lXTgAE2hZjga8iDBWqFwckWO7B0hwKn6IepORBeux0mCt4-Cnm9Ht-ORigQB9P6WAQmIp-MwAaiBAMsdTG3D4kjaHS6PX+ATcyDoAEZ0cZ3JAmM4PIF3HQAEy4ugjI4nch7A6fW6kKLnIkEsCPEIvERvELEMxbSIOGIIciaCAAYW07UwvHSvXZlJGaQAfIyyLt9rh2cpeCxxGABAByAA6ICNlmUGhYAj6EiV6TVNOZwrAdmlIEwf3h-Cg8ri2GiyhgoFWtts5BCyrV5GUkGkdoGlks3NIwBgvR0Mu9TWg1M5Ezdth91w1IXlWc9OYRUFT41dyDU8quVs0OgE5BTnPTvTU+e2xwKBTQnhYKCNtEYrAAsm3tABBKBQOCeI3IYBykDoN1wXi8YB0EBwABGPli6Fio-HJiGeOQql1rmM5jMRuUnMaCIEahMAAYzO4D5qLq4hIAIWLJnWxx0lqyAlgID7fsgu6ZLeCj3qoaEvpBnK8k8YwwQyzr1o4FxiBIYzPMIwRdkQwRAA)